# Очень долгий запуск bat как исправить?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, cmd, bat

Запускаю бота через bat файл и он запускается примерно через полторы минуты. Дело не в коде 100%, потому что я скинул другу весь код и у него на пк всё отлично работает
Я сделал видео что бы наглядно показать как у меня это работает

[Ютуб](https://youtu.be/-5uVFENvRMc)

Comment: Показывать код на видео - это новый уровень!

Comment: приведите код в виде текста, а так же содержимое bat файла

Comment: 1) `echo on` - есть ли какие выполнения; 2) Смотри диспетчер задач, есть ли процесс и нагрузка

Comment: @MaxDown сделал eho on и там только моя проверка через print в начале когда по типу print('Если бот до сих пор тупит, то проблемы в коде') в коде всё отлично потому принт печатает одновременно с включением бота, а в диспетчере нагрузка только он яндекса от службы узла SysMain и Pycharm